# Why standard input is not redirected from console keyboard to text file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a simple powershell script:

```
$stdin = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new([System.Console]::OpenStandardInput())

while (!$stdin.EndOfStream) {
    $line = $stdin.ReadLine()
    $output = "Processed: $line"
    [System.Console]::Out.WriteLine($output)
}
```

if I start the powershell console and insert following command:
`type myfile.txt | ./myscript.ps1` the script doesn't read the lines of the file as I expect, rather it reads the standard keyboard console input. Why is it so? How could I read text lines in script through the pipeline?

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, the host application (in most cases `powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe`) takes care of I/O for the scripts you execute.

If you want to take arbitrary pipeline input in your scripts, use the automatic `$Input` enumerator variable:

```
# myscript.ps1

$Input |ForEach-Object {
  $line = $_
  Write-Host "Processed: '$line'"
}
```

Now you can do:

```
type myfile.txt | ./myscript.ps1
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the answer! I encountered two intereseting things:
1. it seems like the whole content of the text file is buffered before "ForEach" processing starts, is it possible?
2. if I add a definition of a non-mandatory argument, it ends up with a error message "The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input".

Argument definition:
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$Pattern
)

Comment: @Rexxowski 1. No, that's not true - `type` (alias for `Get-Content`) will read and output 1 line at a time for `ForEach-Object` to consume. 2. This is expected behavior - as soon as you start declaring parameter attributes, PowerShell goes "oh, the author wants complete control over the input" at which point [you'll have to handle pipeline input bindings yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.3#valuefrompipeline-argument)